# How to add more on chart by select more items on multi dropdownlist

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a multiselect dropDownList and a chart,i want my chart to by dynamic to plot more based on my multiselect dropdownlist,but i have no idea, I would appreciate if you give me a hint by a demo or an example.because in the following code,i have a chart which works only based normal dropdownlist not the multiplechioce,

Here is Multiselect:

```
$('#multiselect').kendoMultiSelect({
                          dataTextField: "Text",
                          dataValueField: "Text",
                          valuePrimitive: true,
                          dataSource: result.list_of_parks,

                })
```

here is the chart:

```
  function createChart(data, data_wind) {

                        $("#topMonth").kendoChart({                             
                            series: [{
                                data: data,
                                type: "column",
                                axis: "l100km",
                                field: "productionvalue",
                                categoryField: "name",
                                color: "#228B22"
                            },
                                {
                                    axis: "ava",
                                    data: data_wind,
                                    type: "line",
                                    field: "windvalue",
                                    categoryField: "name",
                                    color: "#007eff",
                                },
                            ],
                            valueAxes: [
                                     {
                                         name: "l100km",
                                         title: { text: "Production (MW/H)" },
                                         //  min: 0,
                                         // max: 2000000,
                                         // majorUnit: 200000,

                                         majorGridLines: {
                                             visible: false
                                         },
                                         minorGridLines: {
                                             visible: false
                                         },

                                     },
                                 {
                                     name: "ava",
                                     title: { text: "Averge Wind Speed(KM/H)" },
                                     min: 0,
                                     // max: 20,                        
                                     majorUnit: 1,
                                     majorGridLines: {
                                         visible: false
                                     },
                                     minorGridLines: {
                                         visible: false
                                     },

                                 }
                            ],
                            categoryAxis: {
                                majorGridLines: {
                                    visible: false
                                }
                             ,
                                labels: {
                                    padding: {
                                        left: -20,
                                        buttom: 0
                                    },
                                    rotation: 340

                                },

                                axisCrossingValues: [0, 20],
                            },
                            tooltip: {
                                visible: true,

                                // majorUnit:10,
                                template: " #= value #"
                            },



                        });

                        $(window).on("resize", function () {
                            kendo.resize($(".chart-wrapper"));
                        });
                    }

                }

                   });
        });
```

Comment: Are you trying to show and hide series based on the multiselect selection? Can you show us what your data JSON looks like?

Comment: The series.data needs to be set to the selected values in the multi-select. Do you have a button to refresh the chart, that is ideally where you would re-bind your data.

Comment: @RossBush the standard way is to rebind data?and refresh it?even if it takes seconds?

Comment: @moris1983 - Those charts do not support dynamic changes on the series.

Comment: @RossBush whats your suggestion?this is really bad,please give me a direction

Comment: @moris1983 - You have to give the chart new data for the new series. The chart is just drawing what you give it. Unless you have the data stashed away somewhere client side, you have to make a round trip. The redraw of the chart should be very fast. I would just refresh the chart supplying new data based on the selecteditems in the multi select. Here is a link to another solution --> https://www.telerik.com/forums/how-to-add-multiple-lines-series-dynamically-in-chart -->http://jayeshgoyani.blogspot.in/2013/05/how-to-add-multiple-lines-series.html

Comment: Can you create a demo of your code?